# $.append (); is not working from an external javascript

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to add a navigation bar on top and because i will lots of separate html file, i want to keep the navigation in one file, so incase i make changes it changes in all the pages. If i enter the code in the page itself it works just fine but when its in an external file it gives a different view.

The Jquery snippet is:

```
var snippet =   '   <div id="topMainNav">' +
    '   <ul>' +
    '       <li class="mainNav">' +
    '           <a href="" class="navlink">Find a Doctor</a>' +
    '       </li>' +
    '       <li class="mainNav">' +
    '           <a href="" class="navlink">Why Interfaith</a>' +
            '               <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown_one">' +
    '               <div class="subMainNav" style="padding: 10px;">History & Mission</div>' +
    '               <div class="subMainNav" style="padding: 10px;">Executive Director</div>' +
    '               <div class="subMainNav" style="padding: 10px;">Locations & Directions</div>' +
    '               <div class="subMainNav" style="padding: 10px;">Service Centers</div>' +
    '               <div class="subMainNav" style="padding: 10px;">Career Opportunities</div>' +
    '               <div class="subMainNav" style="padding: 10px;">News & Events</div>' +
    '               <div class="subMainNav" style="padding: 10px;">Parking</div>' +
    '               <div class="subMainNav" style="padding: 10px;">Places To Stay</div>' +
    '           </div>' +
    '       </li>' +
    '       <li class="mainNav">' +
    '           <a href="" class="navlink">Medical Services</a>' +
    '           <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown_two">' +
    '               <div class="subMainNav" style="padding: 10px;"><a href="#">Behavioral Health</a></div>' +
    '               <div class="subMainNav" style="padding: 10px;">Clinical Laboratory</div>' +          
    '               <div class="subMainNav" style="padding: 10px;">Dentistry</div>' +
    '               <div class="subMainNav" style="padding: 10px;">Emergency</div>' +      
    '               <div class="subMainNav" style="padding: 10px;">Gynecology</div>' +
    '               <div class="subMainNav" style="padding: 10px;">Medicine</div>' +         
    '               <div class="subMainNav" style="padding: 10px;">Pastoral</div>' +
    '               <div class="subMainNav" style="padding: 10px;">Pediatrics</div>' +
    '               <div class="subMainNav" style="padding: 10px;">Physical Medicine & Rehab</div>' +
    '               <div class="subMainNav" style="padding: 10px;">Radiology</div>' +
    '               <div class="subMainNav" style="padding: 10px;">Surgery</div>' +
    '               <div class="subMainNav" style="padding: 10px;">Other Services</div>' +
    '           </div>' +
    '       </li>' +
    '       <li class="mainNav">' +
    '           <a href="" class="navlink">Medical Trainings</a>' +
    '           <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown_three">' +
    '               <div class="subMainNav" style="padding: 10px;">Medical Training</div>' +
    '               <div class="subMainNav" style="padding: 10px;">Behavioral Health</div>' +
    '               <div class="subMainNav" style="padding: 10px;">Predoctoral Externship</div>' +
    '               <div class="subMainNav" style="padding: 10px;">Podiatric Residency</div>' +          
    '               <div class="subMainNav" style="padding: 10px;">Dental Residency</div>' +
    '               <div class="subMainNav" style="padding: 10px;">Pulmonary Residency</div>' +
    '           </div>' +
    '       </li>' +
    '       <li class="mainNav">' +
    '           <a href="" class="navlink">For Patients & Visitors</a>' +
    '           <div class="dropdown" id="dropdown_four">' +
    '               <p><a href="#">This is a Link</a></p>' +
    '               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin blandit sodales justo, id fringilla eros dapibus vitae. Morbi molestie enim diam, a vulputate neque. Morbi sit amet nunc.</p>' +
    '           </div>' +
    '       </li>' +
    '       <li class="mainNav">' +
    '           <a href="" class="navlink">Contact Us</a>' +
    '       </li>' +
    '   </ul>' +
    '</div>';

$(function(){$('.writeNav').append (snippet);});
```

on my HTML page i have the following:

```
calling the external jscript file:
<script type="text/javascript" src="theScriptsStyles/miscScripts.js"></script>
```

and in the body of the html i have this:

```
<div class="writeNav"></div>
```

What its suppose to do is, have a pull down menu, so as i put my mouse over it has a slide down menu which is not working. Anyone can please tell me what i am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Can you see if the file is being referenced correctly and there are no 404 errors?

Comment: Why don't you have a `nav.html` file and just do `$(".writeNav").load("nav.html")` on all pages? Sounds a bit cleaner than the string concatenation you have now.

Comment: The line that calls JQuery (`$(function(){$('.writeNav').append (snippet);});`) must be called _after_ jquery is included. I think...

Comment: I would suggest you use `load()` and move the html and all those inline css styles to separate files.

Comment: I think the append is done AFTER you add your event listeners for mouse over.

Comment: Jquery was already called in the HEAD section and there are no error, it just pretty much expands the entire UL list so the mouseover does not work.

Comment: the .LOAD(holdNAV.htm) method also had the same effect. :( the holdNAV.htm page by itself loads just fine. So i think it is a calling the script/css issue.

Comment: I also noticed, that the rest of my CSS classes does not load if the menu is messed up, so i am wondering if it's stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think ,your script is getting loaded even before the div is created. That is why it is not able to find and element with that Class./ Check if that is the case

Comment: Check your console. IF this is the case, you should have an error with null or undefined or something like that .